# Dozer Nested Mapping Convertors

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, dozer

I have a object model B which contains a number of classes. All these classes have array elements defined at various levels in the hierarchy. I have object model A which similarly named classes in a different package. The array elements are defined as complex objects and these complex objects have a list within them. I am able to map these by specifically mapping these using class names. However I want to define a generic method which does this mapping irrespective of the object type. How can define a common method that intercepts all objects of these type and executes a common logic to map this data?

```
class A{
    private ComplexType type;
    private NewComplexType type1;
    //Constructors & getters    
}

class B{
    private String[] type;
    private String[] type1;
    //Constructors & getters 
}

class ComplexType{
     private List<String> list;
    //Getter for the list, no constructor
}

class ComplexType1{
     private List<String> list;
    //Getter for the list, no constructor
}



<mapping>
  <class-a>A</class-a>
  <class-b>B</class-b>
  <field>
    <a>type.list</a>
    <b>type</b>
  </field>

  <field>
    <a>type1.list</a>
    <b>type1</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Can you supply the code for the specific mapping B to A? Then it would be easier to discuss a mapping of "something similar to B" to "something similar to A".

Comment: Hi Laune , I have updated the mapping. I have a number of classes which have similar structure. Hence I have to manually define mapping for all these classes. I wanted to see if I can intercept dozer mapper and have a generic logic which will apply to elements structured like this.

Comment: Hmm, so if you want to use Dozer's XML definition you'll have to generate a set of such XML mappings. Given classes A and B, this could be done using reflection to investigate A and B and to generate a Mapping object. This, then, could be marshalled to XML using JAXB to produce the XML you have added. The code for this is simple.  (BTW: Why is tag JAXB in your question?)

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the reason for adding JAXB in my post. I am exposing a webservice which consumes another webservice. I am using JAXB to create requests and response for the service that I am consuming. I have created my own domain model  which has all the classes and fields similar to what  is generated by JAXB. My service just maps the fields to JAXB request object , makes a call to external service , maps it to my data model and returns the response back. I have 100s of classes , so I don't want to map everything by hand.

Comment: So I wanted to check if I can build a generic logic which can be used to  map all the fields in a generic fashion instead of having to specify one by one.

Comment: Sorry Laune ,  re-read your comment and understood the approach. Can you please help in pointing me to this code? "this, then, could be marshalled to XML using JAXB to produce the XML you have added. The code for this is simple. "

Comment: You need a Java class capable of representing what goes into a `<mapping>`, and possibly another one that collects these into another element, as expected by the Dozer XML syntax. Then you create this gob of data. As for marshalling, see e.g. https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/ and/or other resources on the web.

Comment: Hi Laune , thanks. I have the classes generated by jaxb and am able to send request to the web service. However I'm trying to map my domain model to jaxb model and vice versa. For this I'm having define all the mapping in xml. There are around 500 classes , so I guess it would be time consuming to map the same pattern over and over for different variables. Is there a way to intercept the mapper and probably using reflections , apply the mapping to all classes without having to map each and every class in xml?

Comment: Why don't you send your domain model objects to the web service? There is no gain in class B in your question; it just appears to stringify the complex object. - But, since you have decided to have this all in parallel, you'll need the mapping mechanism. Probably much better to define this via the XML language than to try and do it on the fly.

Comment: I am exposing my service as rest service and the service that I'm consuming is soap service. I don't want to provide my consumers data model filled with xml namespace and jaxb beans. Hence I'm defining my own data model ..

Comment: I didn't say that you have to adapt your packages to XML namespaces, or  that you have to use JAXB beans. It is possible to marshal and unmarshal application classes, exercising control over what goes on the line and how.

Comment: Can I use BeanFactory to intercept and create the beans? Can I set the mapping values as well in addition to creating beans?                                         <configuration>
  <stop-on-errors>true</stop-on-errors>
  <wildcard>true</wildcard>
  <bean-factory>com.example.factories.SomeDefaultBeanFactory
  </bean-factory>
</configuration>